# Convert a string in tuple to a standalone string

Tags: python

I have looked through several StackOverflow questions, and I couldn't find any that answers this question.

How do I convert something like

```
p = ('test2')
```

to

```
p = 'test2'
```

i.e, how do I break a tuple?

Comment: `p` is already a string, just use `str(p)` to explicitly convert it

Comment: Try `str(p)`. ...

Comment: That's not a tuple, it's already a string

Answer (score 2):

If `p` is tuple,

It means,

```
p = ('test2',)
print(p[0])
'test2' # output
```

If is not a tuple,

```
p = ('test2')
print(p)
'test2' # output
```

You need to mention the index value to get the element of tuple.

**Note:** Please note that there is `,`( `comma`) in first example.

Comment: Updated the answer.